# Is it secure to pass a password to Java from Jquery ajax callback in plain text?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, security, servlets

Or do I need to encrypt it first.  I'm using a password text field, grabbing it with

```
var pwd = $("#userpassword").val();
```

and then

```
$.post('JavaServlet', { formData: formData, pwd: pwd, date: date }, function(data) {
```

The java piece encrypts it and stores it in the ldap.
If you suggest to encrypt, please suggest the best way to accomplish the task. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer:  We are using SSL. So it seems redundant to encrypt the password.

Comment: It's never OK to have a password in plain text.

Comment: @pnkflydgr: Please feed the community by reading your previous questions and marking the acceptable answers as ... accepted.

Comment: Does the entire request go over SSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not considered secure unless you use SSL of at least 128-bit encryption, which by the way, it was broken in 2010's. Using as hashed password is a bit safer than plaintext, easier, less resource intensive and might be enough for you, depending on your requirements.

More info on [Protecting Passwords with javascript md5](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/auth.html) (a hash) and some libraries in javascript [here](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/). I understand one of them was used by yahoo many years.

Answer (score 5):

It's **not** secure, unless you use **SSL/TLS** (Https). All information you send over HTTP is sent from the client to the server in clear text.

Comment: ... and can be captureded (or altered) by the man in the middle, right. )

Comment: Actually there should be clarification from the OP on what they want the password secured from.